# Tensorflow c++ memory leak - Valgrind

Tags: c++, tensorflow, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am executing simple tensorflow code to create graph def as shown

```
tensorflow::NewSession (options, &session)
ReadBinaryProto (tensorflow::Env::Default(), "/home/ashok/eclipseWorkspace/faceRecognition-x86_64/Data/models/optimized_facenet.pb", &graph_def));
session->Create (graph_def);
```

But when I run Valgrind as shown below

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --vex-guest-max-insns=25 ./faceRecognition-x86_64 -r -i
```

I get below errors

```
==12366== 16,000 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 47,782 of 47,905
==12366==    at 0x4C2E19F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12366==    by 0xBF875DC: std::vector<tensorflow::CostModel::MemUsage, std::allocator<tensorflow::CostModel::MemUsage> >::reserve(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so)
==12366==    by 0xBF90128: tensorflow::CostModel::InitFromGraph(tensorflow::Graph const&) (in /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so)
==12366==    by 0xBEE48D3: tensorflow::SimpleGraphExecutionState::InitBaseGraph(tensorflow::BuildGraphOptions const&) (in /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so)
==12366==    by 0xBEE52CF: tensorflow::SimpleGraphExecutionState::MakeForBaseGraph(tensorflow::GraphDef*, tensorflow::SimpleGraphExecutionStateOptions const&, std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::SimpleGraphExecutionState, std::default_delete<tensorflow::SimpleGraphExecutionState> >*) (in /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so)
==12366==    by 0xBE68B9D: tensorflow::DirectSession::MaybeInitializeExecutionState(tensorflow::GraphDef const&, bool*) (in /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so)
==12366==    by 0xBE68CF9: tensorflow::DirectSession::ExtendLocked(tensorflow::GraphDef const&) (in /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so)
==12366==    by 0xBE68FC7: tensorflow::DirectSession::Create(tensorflow::GraphDef const&) (in /usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so)
==12366==    by 0x26B899: TensorFlow::initializeRecognition() (in /home/ashok/eclipseWorkspace/faceRecognition-x86_64/Debug/faceRecognition-x86_64)
==12366==    by 0x24197D: RecognitionWithImages::RecognitionWithImages() (in /home/ashok/eclipseWorkspace/faceRecognition-x86_64/Debug/faceRecognition-x86_64)
==12366==    by 0x12F27C: main (in /home/ashok/eclipseWorkspace/faceRecognition-x86_64/Debug/faceRecognition-x86_64)
```

These type of errors are also generated when I do **session -> run ()**

Due to the above issues, the memory needed to run the program keeps increasing as time passes and the application crashes due to insufficient memory after a certain point of time

Answer (score 1):

Did you close the session ? You also need to delete the Session pointer.

```
session->Close();
delete session;
```